# Round off scale/size, rotation and position values in multiple objects in Cinema 4D

Tags: python, c++, 3d, cinema-4d

I'm new to Cinema 4D and I need help.
I use Cinema 4D 2024.
I need to automatically round the scale/size, rotation and position of the selected objects.
I have this need because I work with product design.
Rhino has a similar resource, but I need this feature in Cinema 4D 2024.
Using a script would be great, but I don't know how to develop scripts or Python.
It can be script, plugin or tool.

Any help is welcome.
Currently I do these modifications manually, one object at a time. 
But it is very difficult in projects with hundreds of geometries.
So I need to round the scale, rotation and automatically position 3D models imported to Cinema 4D.

Example:
Selected geometry in Cinema 4D 2024

Coordinates:
X: 24.8033cm
Y: 22.2041cm
Z: 21.2099cm

Rotation:
X: 0.45°
Y: 0.11°
Z: 0.24°

The result I need:
Coordinates:
X: 25cm
Y: 22cm
Z: 22cm

Rotation:
X: 0°
Y: 0°
Z: 0°

I need this feature to work individually on each of the multiple selection objects.

Thanks

I tried to make these changes manually. Rounding the size, position and rotation values. But it is impossible to do it manually on multiple 3D meshes in Cinema 4D.

Comment: Why is this tagged "c++"?

Comment: I asked myself the same question, but it turns out this "cinema 4d" program has a C++ extension SDK.